# How to catch error inside a callback in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have a function like so,

```
Future<void> fn() async {
  await http.get("url1", () async {
    await http.get("url2");
  });
}
```

And then I call this as so,

```
Future<void> call() async {
  try {
    await fn();
  } catch(e) {
    print(e); // Error for http.get("url2") is not shown.
  }
}
```

How do I catch error of `http.get("url2")` inside `call()`?

Comment: Use `try..catch` or `then..catchError` and you could use `raise` also; I'd suggest to keep both GET requests separate.

Comment: I used http just as an example. I just have a use case that requires async callback inside.

Comment: Isn't it possible to catch all errors inside `call` function?

Comment: What `http.get()` function are you calling? [`get()` from `package:http`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html) does not take a callback as an argument.  Can you provide an actual case and what seems to be a completely made-up example?

Comment: also, @jamesdlin is right. what package you have used?

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
Future<void> fn() async {
    await http.get("url1", () async {
      try{
        await http.get("url2");
      } catch (e){
        print(e);
      }
    });
  };
```

the catch inside `fn` would grab the exception for a second service call and the other catch inside the `call` function would show the exception of the outer layer! also, you can `throw` error after logging it to have one single exception handler.